# Spanish characters are not displayed by browser

Tags: html, xml, utf-8, meta, iso-8859-1

I need to support Spanish language for a website which I am developing. I have created an XML file which contains the english text and corresponding Spanish text. I am reading this XML file on user's choice (language dropbox). Everything is working fine unless there are some spanish characters which browser is not able to display properly.

[image]

The content of XML file is:

```
<Spanish>
    <title></title>
    <loginBoxHeader1>Login Panel -</loginBoxHeader1>
    <loginBoxHeader2>Por favor, proporcione las credenciales siguientes!</loginBoxHeader2>
    <username>Nombre de Usuario:</username>
    <password>Contraseña:</password>
    <LoginBtn>iniciar la sesión</LoginBtn>
    <RememberCheckbox>Recordar mi usuario en este equipo</RememberCheckbox>
</Spanish>
```

characters `ñ` and `ó` are not visible in browser. I set encoding of XML file to ISO-8859-1. Also I added following meta tag in HTML page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO 8859-1">
```

I also tried with UTF-8 encoding but problem persists.  Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try saving the XML encoded in UTF-8 as well, or just setting the content-type in the HTML?

Comment: yes i tried but not working...

Comment: As @Wooble points out, you probably saved the document encoded in something different than UTF or ISO. You should go to your text editor, change the encoding of the file to one of those and do the same with the meta tag.

Comment: @NidaSulheri did you find the fix for this?

Comment: Nops... it was long time ago, I don't remember that project :P

Answer (score 1):

have you tried google fonts? http://www.google.com/fonts  Click on "New to Google Fonts?" and follow the steps. I picked 1, just "Normal 400", followed the steps. I had the same problem, my spanish characters would show up as black diamonds with question marks on them.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the fonttype doesn't support the special characters? I have had the same problem before and it was just becuase the font didn't have the symbols in it. 
Changed the font and problem solved.

Comment: Hi, I removed the css file loaded page without any styling but the problem persists. When i encode xml file in UTF-8 then content does not appear at all.

Comment: Do you have cacheing turned off on your server?

Answer (score 0):

Your page is decoded with utf-8 (but should in iso...), the reason can be:

- page file itself is utf-8 encoded (in that case meta tags are ignored)
- www server content-type header is utf-8 (and should be changed to iso...)

Or go other way and save xml in utf-8 using for example notepad++

Answer (score 0):

As @pawlakppp mentioned, have you checked the Encoding of your xml file.
Try this -

- Open the XML file in an editor like  NOTEPAD++.
- Go to 'Encoding' Menu
- Click on 'Encofing with UTF-8' or 'Encoding with UTF-8 without BOM'.